# How to get strings between 2 brackets, in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a large one-dimensional array in C:

```
char MyBigArray [200] = "(Just one more chance)(Another dance)(And let me feel it isn't real that I've been losing you)(This sun will rise)(Within your eyes)(Come back to me and we will be happy together)";
```

Now, I want to print these texts into screen, or make a two-dimensional array, which contains these texts:

```
Just one more chance
Another dance
And let me feel it isn't real that I've been losing you
This sun will rise
Within your eyes
Come back to me and we will be happy together
```

Could you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want the code to make the conversion?

Comment: I would suggest creating an array of pointers to the start of the substrings and probably modify the closing parentheses to mark the end of each substring. Lookup `strchr` and/or `strtok`.

Comment: Do you need to do this in your program, or only in your source code file? (Because the latter is a simple find-and-change operation (with a good editor).)

Comment: You should consider how difficult it will be to write this code if you don't clearly specify the rules, for example are spaces allowed between parenthesized groups?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, this should works

```
char MyBigArray[200] = "(Just one more chance)(Another dance)(And let me feel it isn't real that I've been losing you)(This sun will rise)(Within your eyes)(Come back to me and we will be happy together)";
char MyExportArray[200][200];
int i = 0, j, l = 0, c;
while (MyBigArray[i] != '\0') {
  if (MyBigArray[i] != '(') {
    j = i;
    c = 0;
    while (MyBigArray[j] != ')') {
      MyExportArray[l][c] = MyBigArray[j];
      c++;
      j++;
    }
    MyExportArray[l][c] = '\0';
    l++;
    i = j + 1;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is too dificult to understand. Write clearer code with good variable names and good white space usage, and with comments explaining any non-obvious parts.

Comment: First character is missed from each string. in the output you get `ust one more chance` etc

Comment: Its too simple though, i just put caracter per caracter in the new array, when it reach a ) it pass to the following line. Simple not?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's simple when it's anreadable, and ugly. I would DOWNVOTE again if I could.

Comment: @SimoE. Don't use your mobile for that .

Comment: @SimoE. It is working now that you have made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to parse the strings at the delimeters `"()"`.

Steps involved:

1. Parse strings using `strtok()`
2. If non-empty string, and valid length, copy to export array, using [`strcpy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) from `<string.h>`.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until no more strings to parse

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSTRLEN 200
#define NUMSTR 200

int
main(void) {
    char MyBigArray[MAXSTRLEN] = "(Just one more chance)"
                                 "(Another dance)"
                                 "(And let me feel it isn't real that I've been losing you)"
                                 "(This sun will rise)(Within your eyes)"
                                 "(Come back to me and we will be happy together)";

    char MyExportArray [NUMSTR][MAXSTRLEN];
    char *sentence;
    const char *delim = "()";
    int count = 0, i;

    /* Parsing of the strings */
    sentence = strtok(MyBigArray, delim);

    /* Keep parsing until non-empty string occurs */
    while (sentence != NULL) {

        /* checking if string length is suitable */
        if (strlen(sentence) >= MAXSTRLEN) {
            printf("Sentence too long.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Copy over into array using strcpy */
        strcpy(MyExportArray[count], sentence);
        count++;

        sentence = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    /* Check if number of strings allowed has exceeded */
    if (count > NUMSTR) {
        printf("Too many sentences, Export array not big enough.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* print out export array */
    printf("Your Export array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("MyExportArray[%d] = %s\n", i, MyExportArray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Your Export array:
MyExportArray[0] = Just one more chance
MyExportArray[1] = Another dance
MyExportArray[2] = And let me feel it isn't real that I've been losing you
MyExportArray[3] = This sun will rise
MyExportArray[4] = Within your eyes
MyExportArray[5] = Come back to me and we will be happy together
```

Comment: Please note that `strtok()` is not reentrant. And you can always do the same with `strchr()` without any extra problems, also `strtok()` requires the target string to be writeable and it modifies it. While `strchr()` doesn't. Your code is very good though, I really like it.

Comment: @iharob Could you add an answer with `strchr()`?, I'm not too good with it haha :P